# Does the Yang Mills Mass Gap represent "Absolute Bottom"?

Tags: yang-mills, foundations

The question of the existence of a Yang Mills mass gap is a complex and technical one.

In [this paper](http://vixra.org/abs/1811.0246) Philip Gibbs asks "Is fundamentality then a relative concept with no absolute bottom, or is there a fundament of physical law which is not derived from anything deeper? "

Are these two questions the same?  I ask specifically, is the question of whether or not $\Delta >0$ one and the same question as whether there is an "absolute bottom" as P Gibbs puts it?

Comment: Looks like you want to solve one of Millennium Prize Problems.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't think an answer to this question would get us much closer to that! If I could just understand the problem statement of this particular problem I'd be a lot happier!

Comment: No, they are utterly unrelated. Some QFTs have a mass gap, others do not.